# Windows Service to execute `npm start` on my NodeJS project directory

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-services

I have created a `service.js` script utilizing `os-service` npm package, which I am able to install and run successfully as a Windows Service using following command on Windows.

```
sc create my-service binPath="\"D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe\"  \"D:\workspace\my-service\service.js\"" start=auto
```

**Problem:** `node service.js` is not the right way my script works. I have to run it using `npm start` in order to perform some other useful tasks before running the actual script.

So I need a way to start my Windows Service executing`npm start` on my project directory. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `nssm.exe` instead of `sc.exe` to create my Windows Service which runs my `.bat file` in my project folder. It works like a charm :)

Here are the contents of my `.bat file`

```
cd /d %~dp0
npm start
```